# Is this query irreducibly complex?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, self-join

I have two MySQL database tables, described below. One table holds device information, and the other is a one-to-many log about each device.

```
CREATE TABLE  `device` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `active` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  INDEX (`active`)
);

CREATE TABLE  `log` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `device_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `message` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `when` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  INDEX (`device_id`)
);
```

What I want to do is grab device information along with the latest log entry for each device in a single query (if possible). So far, what I have is the following:

```
SELECT d.id, d.name, l.message
FROM device AS d
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT l1.device_id, l1.message
  FROM log AS l1
  LEFT JOIN log AS l2 ON (l1.device_id = l2.device_id AND l1.when < l2.when)
  WHERE l2.device_id IS NULL
) AS l ON (d.id = l.device_id)
WHERE d.active = 1
GROUP BY d.id
ORDER BY d.id ASC;
```

These queries are simplified reproductions of my actual setup, where my log table is over 100k rows (and there are actually several log tables I look at). The query does run, however very, very slowly (say, more than two minutes). I'm convinced that there is a more concise/elegant/"SQL" way to form this query to get the data I need, but I just haven't found it yet.

Is what I want to do even possible without the ugly sub-SELECT and self-JOIN? Can I get the job done with a different strategy? Or, is the very nature of the query something that is irreducibly complex?

Again, the application logic is such that I can "manually JOIN" the tables if this isn't going to work, but I feel like MySQL should be able to handle something like this without choking - but I'm admittedly green when it comes to this kind of complex set algebra.

**EDIT:** As this is a contrived example, I'd forgotten to add the index to `device.active`

Comment: Should you add an index on (device_id, when) ? That might make the JOIN a lot more efficient.

Comment: As you've experienced first hand MySQL gets slower and slower the bigger the queries are, the more data you store etc. If you have in your case over 100k of rows I would recommend using a different solution: NoSQL

Comment: @libjup, without meaning to put the OP down 100k rows isn't large, at all, it's fairly small actually. Recommending changing not only RDBMS but DBMS because there is a 100k table is a massive over-reaction.

Comment: How selective is `active` in the advice table? It would probably help to index this and add one on (`id`, `active`) depending. Also as @IanClelland says you should probably have a different index on `log`. What is the explain plan of your query?

Comment: Well I'm not sure about that, Ben. Even though I don't know for sure, I assume that it won't come to a stop at 100k of rows (OP has just started with his code). Also if you have a look at his query: It consits of Joins and a Group-By. That's exactly that kind of stuff NoSQL is powerful for and isn't it always better to use the appropriate technologies right away than change everything later on?

Comment: You mention that there are multiple log tables that you're pulling from... how does the query perform if you pull only from 1 log table?  What about only 2 log tables?  Even without proper indexing, this query shouldn't take more than a few seconds, so I'm guessing that your query might be creating a Cartesian product when incorporating the multiple log tables...

Comment: Elegance is almost always an inappropraite measure when writing SQL code. Performance is critical.

Comment: @libjup: "Also if you have a look at his query: It consits of Joins and a Group-By. That's exactly that kind of stuff NoSQL is powerful for". So true!!! And /dev/null is webscale too!

Comment: @libjup: Are you suggesting that this sort of operation would be performed *more* efficiently with a NoSQL solution? If so, can you please elaborate? It seems to me that NoSQL would, in fact, explicitly prevent me from this kind of logic. Also, as @ Ben has commented, 100k is a small amount of data indeed - I don't see how "later on" I'm left with no choice but to abandon the RDBMS.

Comment: @Chris, have you tried my suggestion? Curious if that worked for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a slightly different approach to your query that avoids the self-join:

```
SELECT d.id, d.name, l.message
FROM device AS d
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT l1.device_id, l1.message
  FROM log AS l1
  WHERE l1.when = (
        SELECT MAX(l2.when)
        FROM log AS l2
        WHERE l2.device_id = l1.device_id
  ) l ON l.device_id = d.id
WHERE d.active = 1
ORDER BY d.id ASC;
```

Since 100k isn't a very large table, even without the proper indexes I wouldn't expect this query to take more than a few seconds.  However, like the comments suggest, you might consider adding additional indexes based on the results of your `explain plan`.

Comment: Good one, but may be MAX() instead of MIN()?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative that requires only one instance of the log table:

```
SELECT    d.id, d.name, 
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(
              GROUP_CONCAT(
                  l.message 
                  SEPARATOR '~' 
                  ORDER BY l.when DESC
              ) 
          ,   '~'
          ,   1
          )
FROM      device d
LEFT JOIN log    l
ON        d.id = l.device_id
WHERE     d.active = 1
GROUP BY  d.id
```

This query finds the last log message by creating a tilde-separated list of messages, sorted by the date in descending order. That's done by the `GROUP_CONCAT`. The `SUBSTRING_INDEX` chips of the first entry of that list.

There are 2 drawbacks to this approach:

- it uses `GROUP_CONCAT`. If the result of that function becomes too long, the result is truncated. You can remedy that if you do

  `SET @@group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;`

before running the query. You can do even better than that: since you're only interested in getting only one message, you can set `group_concat_max_len` to be as large as the maximum character length of the `message` column. This will save considerable memory as compared to using `@@max_alowed_packet`.

- it relies on a special separator (in the example, it's tilde (`'~'`)) that must not appear within the message text. You can change this to any separator string you like as long as you're sure it doesn't appear inside the message text.

If you can live with these limitations, then this query is probably the fastest.

Here are more alternatives that are about as complex as yours but may perform better.

```
SELECT    d.id
,         d.name
,         l.message
FROM      (
          SELECT    d.id, d.name, MAX(l.when) lmax
          FROM      device d
          LEFT JOIN log    l
          ON        d.id = l.device_id
          WHERE     d.active  = 1
          GROUP BY  d.id
          ) d
LEFT JOIN log       l
ON        d.id   = l.device_id
AND       d.lmax = l.when
ORDER BY d.id ASC;
```

another alternative:

```
SELECT    d.id
,         d.name
,         l2.message
FROM      device d
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT   l.device_id
          ,        MAX(l.when) lmax
          FROM     log l
          GROUP BY l.device_id
          ) l1
ON        d.id = l1.device_id 
LEFT JOIN log       l2
ON        l1.device_id = l2.device_id
AND       l1.lmax      = l2.when
WHERE     d.active     = 1
ORDER BY  d.id ASC;
```

Comment: the GROUP_CONCAT query is clever. I think you intended to include `SEPARATOR '~'` in the GROUP_CONCAT function, at least, that's the way I read it.

Comment: @spencer7593 thanks! indeed good call, i forgot the separator clause! editing to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Your query, and the strategies below will benefit from an index `ON log(device_id,when)`. That index can replace the index `ON log(device_id)`, since that index would be redundant.

---

If you have a whole boatload of log entries for each a device, the JOIN in your query is going to generate a good sized intermediate result set, which will get filtered down to one row per device. I don't believe the MySQL optimizer has any "shortcuts" for that anti-join operation (at least not in 5.1)... but your query might be the most efficient.

**Q:** Can I get the job done with a different strategy?

Yes, there are other strategies that, but I don't know that any of these is any "better" than your query.

---

**UPDATE:**

One strategy you might consider is adding another table to your schema, one that holds the most recent log entry for each device. This could be maintained by TRIGGERs defined on the `log` table. If you are only performing inserts (no UPDATE and no DELETE of the most recent log entry, this is fairly straightforward. Whenever an insert is performed against the `log` table, an `AFTER INSERT FOR EACH ROW` trigger is fired, which compares the `when` value being inserted into the log table for a device_id, to the current `when` value in the `log_latest` table, and inserts/updates the row in the `log_latest` table so that the most recent row is always there. You could also (redundantly) store the device name in the table.  (Alternatively, you could add a `latest_when` and a `latest_message` columns to the device table, and maintain them there.)

But this strategy goes beyond your original question... but it is a workable strategy to consider if you need to frequently run a "latest log message for all devices" query. The downside is that you have an extra table, and a performance hit when performing inserts to the `log` table. This table could be entirely refreshed using a query like your original one, or the alternatives below.

---

One approach is a query that does a simple join of the `device` and `log` tables, gets the rows ordered by device and by descending `when`. Then use a memory variable to process the rows, to filter out all but the "latest" log entry.  Note that this query returns an extra column.  (This extra column can be removed by wrapping the whole query as an inline view, but you'll likely get better performance if you can live with an extra column being returned:

```
SELECT IF(s.id = @prev_device_id,0,1) AS latest_flag
     , @prev_device_id := s.id AS id
     , s.name
     , s.message
  FROM (SELECT d.id
             , d.name
             , l.message
          FROM device d
          LEFT
          JOIN log l ON l.device_id = d.id
         WHERE d.active = 1
         ORDER BY d.id, l.when DESC
       ) s
  JOIN (SELECT @prev_device_id := NULL) i
HAVING latest_flag = 1
```

What the first expression in the SELECT list is doing is "marking" a row whenever the device id value on that row is DIFFERS from the device id on the PREVIOUS row.  The HAVING clause filters out all of the rows that aren't marked with a 1.  (You can omit the HAVING clause to see how that expression works.)

(I didn't test this for syntax errors, if you get an error, let me know, and I will take a closer look. My desk checking says it's fine... but it's possible I missed a paren or comma,)

(You can "get rid of" that extra column by wrapping that in another query

```
SELECT r.id,r.name,r.message FROM (
/* query from above */
) r
```

(but again, this may impact performance, you'd likely get better performance if you can live with the extra column.)

Of course, add an ORDER BY on the outermost query to guarantee that your resultset is ordered the way you need it.

This approach would work fairly well for a whole bunch of devices, and only a couple of related rows in log. Otherwise, this is going to generate a huge mess of a intermediate result set (on the order of the number of rows in the log table) which is going to have to be spun out to a temporary MyISAM table.

**UPDATE:**

If you are getting essentially all of the rows from `device` (where the predicate is not very selective), you can probably get better performance by getting the latest log entry for every device_id in the `log` table, and postpone the join to the `device` table. (But note that an index will not be available on that intermediate result set to do the join, so it would really need to be tested to gauge performance.)

```
SELECT d.id
     , d.name
     , t.message
  FROM device d 
  LEFT
  JOIN (SELECT IF(s.device_id = @prev_device_id,0,1) AS latest_flag
             , @prev_device_id := s.device_id AS device_id
             , s.messsage
          FROM (SELECT l.device_id
                     , l.message
                  FROM log l
                 ORDER BY l.device_id DESC, l.when DESC
               ) s
          JOIN (SELECT @prev_device_id := NULL) i
        HAVING latest_flag = 1
       ) t
    ON t.device_id = d.id
```

**NOTE:** We specify descending order on both the `device_id` and `when` columns in the ORDER BY clause of the inline view aliased as `s`, not because we need the rows in descending device_id order, but to allow to avoid a filesort operation by allowing MySQL to perform a "reverse scan" operation on an index with leading columns (device_id, when).

**NOTE:** This query still going to spool off intermediate result set as a temporary MyISAM tables, and there won't be any index on those. So its likely this won't perform as well as your original query.

---

Another strategy is to use a correlated subquery in the SELECT list. You are only returning a single column from the log table, so this is fairly easy query to understand:

```
SELECT d.id
     , d.name
     , ( SELECT l.message
           FROM log l
          WHERE l.device_id = d.id
          ORDER BY l.when DESC 
          LIMIT 1
       ) AS message
  FROM device d
 WHERE d.active = 1
 ORDER BY d.id ASC;
```

**NOTE:** Since `id` is the PRIMARY KEY (or a UNIQUE KEY) in the `device` table, and because you aren't doing any JOIN that will generate extra rows, you can omit the `GROUP BY` clause.

**NOTE:** This query will use a "nested loops" operation. That is, for each row returned from the `device` table, (essentially) a separate query needs to be run to get the related row from log. For only a few `device` rows (as would be returned with a more selective predicate on the `device` table), and with a boatload of log entries for each device, performance will not be too bad.  But for a lot of devices which each only have a few log messages, other approaches are very likely going to be much more efficient.)

Also note, with this approach, note that you can easily extend it to also return the second latest log message as a separate column, by adding another subquery (just like that first one) to the SELECT list, just changing the LIMIT clause to skip the first row, and get the second row instead.

```
     , ( SELECT l.message
           FROM log l
          WHERE l.device_id = d.id
          ORDER BY l.when DESC 
          LIMIT 1,1
       ) AS message_2
```

---

For getting basically all the rows from device, you'll likely get the best performance using JOIN operations. The one drawback of this approach is that it has the potential to return multiple rows for a device, when there are two (or more) rows that have a matching latest `when` value for a device.  (Basically, this approach is guaranteed to return a "correct" resultset when we have a guarantee that `log(device_id,when)` is unique.

With this query as an inline view, to get the "latest" when value:

```
SELECT l.device_id
     , MAX(l.when)
  FROM log l
 GROUP BY l.device_id
```

We can join this to the log and device tables.

```
SELECT d.id
     , d.name
     , m.messsage
  FROM device d
  LEFT
  JOIN (
         SELECT l.device_id
              , MAX(l.when) AS `when`
           FROM log l
          GROUP BY l.device_id 
       ) k
    ON k.device_id = d.id
  LEFT
  JOIN log m 
    ON m.device_id = d.id
       AND m.device_id = k.device_id
       AND m.when = k.when
 ORDER BY d.id
```

---

All of these are alternate strategies (which I believe is the question you asked), but I'm not sure either of those is going to be better for your particular needs. (But it's always good to have a couple of different tools in the tool belt, to use as appropriate.)

Comment: Correlated subqueries are almost always the worst performing code. You should never suggest them to replace derived tables. it is the differnce between something that runs row by row and something that runs as a data set. Better to get in the habit of using the right techniques than use poor ones like this.

Comment: @HLGEM: Sometimes, a correlated subquery is the most efficient approach. I actually have some situations where it IS the most efficient approach to returning a specified result set. (I believe I did include in my answer a note about performance concerns with this approach.) Derived tables aren't a magic bullet, they also have some performance considerations. Certainly, you are free to believe that a correlated subquery is an anathema, and you are free to believe it is a "poor technique" and to "never suggest" them. The OP asked for an alternate strategy. And a correlated subquery is just that.

Comment: It seems to me none of these solutions are less complex than the original?

Comment: @Roland, you are probably correct. The "less complex" query is the one that runs against a prepared result set, the data already available in a separate table. The second "less complex" query is the one that uses a correlated subquery in the SELECT list. The queries for each of these approaches has the minimum complexity required to satisfy the specified requirements. The queries in your answer are likely to perform about as well as any, and would likely benefit from an index on `log(device_id,when)`.

Comment: Agree about the index, good call that. In the MySQL case, I actually do think my first query with GROUP_CONCAT will perform best. It's quite easy to confirm or refute that claim.

Comment: @Roland, yes, the GROUP_CONCAT query is clever. (I think that function is missing the delimiter argument, which you are checking for in the SUBSTRING_INDEX function. As you noted in your answer, that strategy does have some limits. In my experience, using a memory variable to detect "control breaks" is sometimes the most efficient. But it depends on data distribution, selectivity, indexes, how many rows are being returned, et al.

Comment: @spencer7593 yes, the variables can help too, but I learned to shun them. They proved to be too unreliable - a simple change in the query or even adding an index or reaching a particular data volume can change the query plan entirely and mess up the order in which the calculations are performed. Look a this post, and read the comments: http://rpbouman.blogspot.nl/2008/07/mysql-percentile-aftermath-calculating.html

Comment: @Roland: yes you do need to be careful with user variables, because MySQL does not guarantee this behavior. You need to take care to construct such queries using inline views. Because MySQL always materializes inline views (unlike Oracle), this essentially forces (and almost guarantees) that the steps in the plan are executed in a particular order. If you don't use inline views, then you are correct that the query plan is unpredictable, and a change in the query plan can mess with the user variable technique; it works only for special cases of SELECT, and should not be used for DML operations.