# NoSql solution for many CSV files

Tags: c#, nosql

What NoSql solution is best for the following requirements? This question is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131443/database-within-a-database-table-design). The amount and names of columns is unknown and can range from 1 to millions of records. My language of choice will be C# and I may need a client to access the data store. The data store will need efficient data paging so if the CSV files has 2 million rows I need an efficient way to navigate to page 2500 and needs to support sorting and advanced filtering. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: he is asking for a nosql store to store his csv files.

Comment: Thats correct but I will not store the csv files as a whole. I will convert the csv file into a table with multiple columns and then store it into nosql data store.

Comment: @Luke101, please back-link related questions. In this case it looks like you're asking about this because you want to implement the approach you asked about in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127814/database-design-to-create-tables-on-the-fly and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131443/database-within-a-database-table-design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use a Document Store, can be mongodb, couchdb.

If you take one row as one document, where as columns may vary this is a good fit for you.

There is no strict schema so columns may vary.

MongoDb has c# support, it has a nice client that takes care of pooling, sharding etc.

It s open source.

It provides all those features you want, easy to query etc.